# Where do extended (decimal, e.g. 400.1, 401.4, etc.) HTTP status codes come from?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

More and more I am seeing the proliferation of decimal style HTTP status codes and I can't seem to find any RFC or other IETF recommendation or even W3C drafts or whatever on this except Microsoft IIS documentation (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943891)

Did Microsoft create these out of thin air? Wouldn't these decimal style status codes choke a lot of network components that might be expecting a whole integer value?

Does anyone know where these decimal status codes come from?

Comment: AFAIU, the Microsoft documentation is very misleading. E.g., you will never ever find a "400.1" in an HTTP response status line, as that would make the response malformed. It might appear in a custom header field or the response body though, but then, this isn't a status code.

Comment: Yeah I agree entirely and we started seeing this in a non-MS setting. The only reason I referred to the IIS documentation is because it's the only actual reference I have found to the decimal-style response codes, so either MS made these up or there is some obscure recommendation somewhere like PEP or whatever that suggests to detail response codes in this format. The only canonical registry AFAIK is IANA's HTTP Status Code Registry (https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml)

Answer (score 3):

Julian's comment above is correct.

IIS defines substatuses to help differentiate cases within the same defined status code for debugging purposes.  These aren't sent on the wire in the HTTP response; as others have noted, that's an integer.  They may appear in the response entity if configured (by default, only for clients running on the same host), and they're logged in the W3C log under the "sc-substatus" column.

If you're seeing decimal status codes elsewhere (the original question), you'd need to follow up with the source of them.  Particularly, if you're seeing them in the HTTP message itself, that's a protocol compliance issue.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943891) you also linked to:

> [...]
> **IIS 7.0, IIS 7.5, and IIS 8.0 define** the following HTTP status codes that indicate a more specific cause of a 400 error:
> 400.1 - Invalid Destination Header.
> 400.2 - Invalid Depth Header.
> 400.3 - Invalid If Header.
> [...]

So yes, IIS defines them.

And from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), there is this gem:

> 

[...]
The first digit of the status code specifies one of five classes of response; **the bare minimum for an HTTP client is that it recognises these five classes**. The phrases used are the standard examples, but any human-readable alternative can be provided.
[...]

So it's only mandatory that it starts with a 1-5.

Even if the HTTP client doesn't understand the whole status code, it can still decide what type of response it is:

- 1xx Informational
- 2xx Success
- 3xx Redirection
- 4xx Client Error
- 5xx Server Error

---

**Update1:**

As stated in [RCF7231#6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6):

> The status-code element **is a three-digit integer code** giving the
> result of the attempt to understand and satisfy the request.

But also:

> HTTP status codes are extensible.  HTTP clients are not required to
> understand the meaning of all registered status codes, though such
> understanding is obviously desirable.  However, a client MUST
> understand the class of any status code, as indicated by the first
> digit, and treat an unrecognized status code as being equivalent to
> the x00 status code of that class, with the exception that a
> recipient MUST NOT cache a response with an unrecognized status code.

For example, if an unrecognized status code of 471 is received by a
client, the client can assume that there was something wrong with its
request and treat the response as if it had received a 400 (Bad
Request) status code.  The response message will usually contain a
representation that explains the status.

---

**Update2:**

Setting a 404.1 header in PHP (although the docs say it only accepts ints)

```
http_response_code(404.1);
```

results in a classic `404`

---

So, in conclusion, I take it, clients, when the status code is unrecognized (for instance a `401.4`), transform it into a generic `400` (keeping the status class - `4` and filling with `00`)

Comment: But that directly contradicts RFC 7231:  

    6.  Response Status Codes
    
    The status-code element is a three-digit integer code giving the
    result of the attempt to understand and satisfy the request.

RFC Clearly states that it's a 3 digit Integer so I wouldn't expect all of network components to understand the decimal value. In fact if they are expecting an integer value would probably just choke.

Comment: @aimass Soo... On one hand there is that rfc. On the other there's Microsoft's kb. Would it surprise you that MS goes against it?

Comment: But that is my point exactly! I have been seeing these decimal status codes in non-MS contexts and when searching for the origin of this I stumbled upon this IIS doc. So not really sure MS made these up are there is some other origin, because I have been seeing them in several places now, nothing to do with MS.

Comment: Just pointing out that Microsoft doesn't go against the RFC -- those codes aren't sent in the HTTP status code.  They're in the entity body and in the log, in order to provide more precision.